# Windows 10 upgrade and Truecrypt

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, truecrypt

Can you safely upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 when using Truecrypt 7.1a without risk of corrupting the bootloader and without first decrypting the drive?

Comment: TrueCrypt has at least two limitations relevant to modern computers: 1) For full-disk-encrytion you need an MBR and not a GPT formated disk and 2) AFAIK it's not compatible with UEFI, so you need to switch to BIOS mode

Comment: @CodesInChaos It's because Im lazy

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Can you safely upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 when using TrueCrypt 7.1a

- TrueCrypt is no longer supported.
- You should decrypt 
  your hard disk and any other data before upgrading as otherwise you cannot be sure you will be able to retrieve your data.

---

#### If you wish to still use unsupported software

> Some people have stated that TrueCrypt still works with Windows 10.

- Decrypt the disk, do the upgrade, then make sure TrueCrypt still functions after the upgrade.
- Make backups should be made before and after you encrypt the HDD and perform that first reboot.

---

> The development of TrueCrypt was ended in 5/2014 after Microsoft terminated support of Windows XP. Windows 8/7/Vista and later offer integrated support for encrypted disks and virtual disk images. Such integrated support is also available on other platforms (click here for more information). You should migrate any data encrypted by TrueCrypt to encrypted disks or virtual disk images supported on your platform.

Source http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net

---

> It is likely to be incompatible. It is always recommended you decrypt
>   your hard disk and any other data before upgrading an operating system
>   or else it will not be accessible after upgrading.

Source [Windows 7 to 10 upgrade: TrueCrypt 7.1a](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-7-to-10-upgrade-truecrypt-71a/0f1c2051-5952-4798-aaf3-874b1b486d04)

Comment: Truecrypt is not supported anymore

Comment: Truecrypt still works great actually

Comment: @FrankThornton "works great" and "not supported" are not mutually exclusive.  However it's likely Win10 and TrueCrypt could have compatibility problems we don't know about

Comment: @woj. Noted. Answer updated.

Comment: Any compatibility problems can be avoided by decrypting the disk, doing the upgrade, then making sure TrueCrypt still functions after the upgrade.  Of course proper backups should be made before and after you encrypt the hdd and perform that first reboot.

Comment: @Ramhound Good point. Added to answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I was just commenting to WoJ's comment actually :$

Comment: Somehow using Microsoft-provided encryption tools feels to me like asking the fox to guard the henhouse...

Comment: @SF. <shrug> that has nothing to do with the question or answer, which is about truecrypt. What point are you trying to make that is relevant to the answer?

Answer (score 29):

Do NOT upgrade on a System-encrypted-TrueCrypt drive!

[you have to decrypt -> upgrade -> encrypt](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-7-to-10-upgrade-truecrypt-71a/0f1c2051-5952-4798-aaf3-874b1b486d04)

Comment: Indeed. Otherwise, the “not-in-Windows” portion of the upgrade process will most likely fail. It will most likely not have the TrueCrypt driver.

Comment: While it would be nice to have something from the link, that says that, the simply fact is this is the proper procedure so there isn't that much that should be added.

Comment: Plus; Windows Backup won't work if you encrypt a disk.

Comment: And use VeraCrypt!

Answer (score 4):

I have **practically tested** 7.1a on Windows 10 on a VMWare environment.

**YES, it does work.** You can use TrueCrypt 7.1a system drive encryption with Windows 10, but in order to do that, you must:

- Un-encrypt the drive
- Update to Windows 10
- Make sure you do not use UEFI Secureboot.
- After Windows 10 is updated, re-encrypt the system drive.

So I confirm **it is compatible with Windows 10 boot system**, but make sure you follow the rules above when updating.

Answer (score 2):

I am running the last stable version of Trucrypt. I recently upgraded to Windows 10. So far Trucrypt appears to be working fine. The upgrade does mess with the security settings on all drives and folders. You may have to give yourself admin on all drives and folders to access Trucrypt container files properly. So far so good

Comment: Do you have any proof for your claim?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are wrong. You do **NOT** have to disable your full-disk system encryption for an upgrade.

For that you need to integrate the Truecrypt or Veracrypt drivers into your W10 installation media. You can do that with this tool: https://github.com/th-wilde/veracrypt-w10-patcher

The upgrade process will not replace your Truecrypt/Veracrypt bootloader. I tested this myself just now.

Answer (score -3):

Truecrypt is no longer developed and has a few known security holes.  Use [Veracrypt](http://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) as a drop-in replacement.  It is fully compatible with Truecrypt as it started development from the last Truecrypt version of the source code.  And as already said it has fixed some security holes that exist in the last available Truecrypt.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question does it?

Comment: It may not, but it lets you know that because of the known security holes in Truecrypt that you actually aren't safe with it.

Comment: Follow the other advice: decrypt the drive, upgrade, and then re-encrypt with Veracrypt.

Comment: Actually the "security" holes in Truecrypt are quite ok and are only benign in general for the security of Truecrypt itself.

Comment: Perhaps, but they will never be fixed.  That alone should be an impetus to move to something that will get future updates.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment.  It's useful, tangential information but doesn't answer what was asked in the question.

Comment: @headkase you should integrate that comment into the answer