# Windows 10, TrueCrypt 7.1a and external HDD

Tags: windows-10, truecrypt

I just upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. Now, using TrueCrypt 7.1a, I can mount my encrypted external HDD but I can no longer seem to access it:

```
H:\ is not accessible.
Incorrect function.
```

Anybody know what to do?

Note: This is not similar to [Windows 10 upgrade and Truecrypt](https://superuser.com/questions/949519/windows-10-upgrade-and-truecrypt) as this is regarding an external HDD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution can be found here:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9968345

Simply rename `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\AppleHFS.sys` to something else and reboot.

Comment: That seems to only apply to those running Bootcamp on an Apple machine.That file doesn't exist on my computer.

Comment: @leetNightshade I can confirm that this does indeed work on Bootcamp since I'm in the same predicament. Answer fixed my problem.